# Are submanifolds defined by quadratic quations exactly the submanifolds given by a quadratic graph representation?

Tags: manifolds, quadratics, surfaces, quadratic-forms, parametrization

Can every manifold that is locally given as the solution to quadratic equations also be locally represented as the graph of a quadratic function?

If not, is this true for a nice subclass of manifolds? Is there an easy counterexample or a reference for this?

My setting of interest in this is mainly $\mathcal{C}^2$ submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ellipse is locally represented by solutions to an equations that's quadratic in each of $x$ and $y$, but is nowhere represented as the graph of a quadratic. But maybe that's not what you meant.

A tilted parabola (e.g., $(y+x)^2 = y - x$) is locally represented by a solution to a quadratic (in $x + y$) but is nowhere the graph of a quadratic in either of $x$ or $y$.

Comment: Thanks, this actually is what I want. However, is there a way to really see that this cannot be a quadratic graph locally in either $x$ or $y$?

Comment: @MaxM: yes, just solve for $x$ or $y$ and observe it is not a quadratic function.  For example, it is not differentiable on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Sure. Look at $x = 0$: at $x = 0$, both  $y = 1$ and $y = -1$ are on the graph. Similarly, for $y = 0$, both $x = 0$ and $x = -1$ are on the graph.